# Dynamically switching in frames in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

```
public boolean dynamicSwitchingFrames(WebElement element) {
    boolean switchStatus = false;
    String parentTag = "";
    WebElement targetElement = element;
    WebElement parentNode=null;

    while (!(switchStatus)) {
        parentNode = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].parentNode;", targetElement);
        parentTag = parentNode.getTagName();

        if (parentTag.equalsIgnoreCase("iframe")) {
            driver.switchTo().frame(parentNode);
            switchStatus = true;
            break;
        }
        targetElement = parentNode;
    }
    return switchStatus;
}
```

We have an web application that has lot of elements inside frames. Is it possible to create a utility that accepts an web element as an argument and switches to frame where that element resides. I tried creating below utility but it doesn't helps
What I want is that for any webelement, utility should find its frame and driver switches to that frame. Above utility is giving me error that it is unable to find element (targetElement).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is you *won't be able* to find an element unless you *switched to a frame* where it is. If you already have an instance of WebElement you most likely know it's frame, because you have switched to it to find an element.

Here is how we dealt with frames it in our projects, having following logic built in our custom driver. It a few words it works like this:

1. look for frame/iframe elements
2. adds them to a list
3. start looking for an element in the first frame, if not found - goes to the next frame from the list and so on. (it's actually bit more complicated as there could be different strategies of a search for elements list like "stop when first found" vs "check in all frames")

You can see the code here. If you don't want to create your own driver as we did, you may just extract the logic and add it to your custom findElementInFrames method:
https://github.com/WileyLabs/teasy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wiley/driver/frames/FramesTransparentWebDriver.java

Comment: Which exact method i need to refer for this?

Comment: findElement and findElements

Answer (score 0):

But don't we already have that feature? below image depicts how we can switch to the frame by element.
Did I read your question wrongly?

[image: Frames]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question

Comment: Aghh!! Thought so. Never mind can you give a try and see if that works

Comment: Actually I didn't get what this picture actually depicts

Comment: When you type driver.switchTo().frame you would get three overloaded methods. One of them accepts webelement. So use ' driver.switchTo().frame(element)'